# What is the difference between composite:insertFacet and composite:renderFacet?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component, facet

I am using GlassFish 3.1.2 and trying to use `composite:insertFacet` in a composite component, but the HTML Markup is not generated when using my CC.

The same code works fine when I use `composite:renderFacet`, but I want to understand why `composite:insertFacet` is not working in that example? and when to use each of them?

This is my `login.xhtml` file (the Composite component implementation, the "**heading**" facet is the issue):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

       <composite:interface>
          <composite:editableValueHolder name="nameInput" targets="form:name"/>
          <composite:editableValueHolder name="passwordInput" targets="form:password"/>
          <composite:editableValueHolder name="inputs"
                targets="form:name form:password"/>
          <composite:actionSource name="loginButton" targets="form:loginButton"/>

          <composite:attribute name="name"/>
          <composite:attribute name="password"/>

          <composite:attribute name="namePrompt"/>
          <composite:attribute name="passwordPrompt"/>

          <composite:attribute name="loginValidate" 
             method-signature="void validateLogin(ComponentSystemEvent e)
                throws javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException"/>

          <composite:attribute name="loginAction" 
             method-signature="java.lang.String action()"/>

          <composite:facet name="heading"/>
          <composite:facet name="error"/> 
       </composite:interface>

       <composite:implementation>
          <h:outputScript library="util" name="login.js" target="head"/>
          <h:form id="form" onsubmit="return checkForm(this, '#{cc.clientId}')">
             <composite:insertFacet name="heading"/>
             <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                #{cc.attrs.namePrompt}
                <h:panelGroup>
                   <h:inputText id="name" value="#{cc.attrs.name}"/>
                   <h:message for="name"/>
                </h:panelGroup>

                #{cc.attrs.passwordPrompt}

                <h:panelGroup>
                   <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{cc.attrs.password}" size="8"/>
                   <h:message for="password"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
             </h:panelGrid>

             <p>
                <h:commandButton id="loginButton"
                   value="#{cc.attrs.loginButtonText}"
                   action="#{cc.attrs.loginAction}"/>
             </p>

          </h:form>

          <composite:renderFacet name="error"/>

          <p><composite:insertChildren/></p>

          <p>#{cc.resourceBundleMap.footer}</p>
       </composite:implementation>
    </html>
```

**index.xhtml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:util="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/util"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
   <h:head>
      <title>#{msgs.loginHeading}</title>
      <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css" />
   </h:head>
   <h:body>
      <util:login namePrompt="#{msgs.namePrompt}"
            passwordPrompt="#{msgs.passwordPrompt}"
            name="#{user.name}"
            password="#{user.password}"
            loginAction="#{user.login}"
            loginButtonText="#{msgs.loginButtonText}">

         <f:validateLength minimum="4" for="nameInput"/>
         <f:validator validatorId="com.corejsf.Password" for="passwordInput"/>
         <f:actionListener type="com.corejsf.LoginActionListener" for="loginButton"/>

         <f:facet name="heading" styleClass="header">
            <div class="prompt">#{msgs.loginPrompt}</div>
         </f:facet>

         <f:facet name="error" styleClass="error">
            <h:messages layout="table" styleClass="error"/>
         </f:facet>

         <!-- Child component -->
         <h:link outcome="register">#{msgs.registerLinkText}</h:link>

      </util:login>
      <ui:debug/>
   </h:body>
</html>
```

I tried to figure out the reason from the Component Tree, but I was more confused as the `insertFacet` appears, here is a the section from the **Component Tree** when using insertFacet:

```
    <UIOutput id="j_idt7" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false">

        <UINamingContainer id="j_idt8" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false">
            error

            <HtmlMessages globalOnly="false" id="j_idt10" inView="true" layout="table" redisplay="true" rendered="true" showDetail="false" showSummary="true" styleClass="error" tooltip="false" transient="false"/>

            javax.faces.component.COMPOSITE_FACET_NAME

            <UIPanel inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false">

                <HtmlForm enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="form" inView="true" onsubmit="return checkForm(this, '')" prependId="true" rendered="true" submitted="false" transient="false">
                    header

                    <div class="prompt">#{msgs.loginPrompt}</div>

                    <HtmlPanelGrid border="-2147483648" columns="2" id="j_idt15" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false">
....
```

The **Component Tree** when using renderFacet:

```
<UIOutput id="j_idt7" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false">

    <UINamingContainer id="j_idt8" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false">
        error

        <HtmlMessages globalOnly="false" id="j_idt10" inView="true" layout="table" redisplay="true" rendered="true" showDetail="false" showSummary="true" styleClass="error" tooltip="false" transient="false"/>

        heading

        <div class="prompt">#{msgs.loginPrompt}</div>

        javax.faces.component.COMPOSITE_FACET_NAME

        <UIPanel inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false">

            <HtmlForm enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="form" inView="true" onsubmit="return checkForm(this, '')" prependId="true" rendered="true" submitted="false" transient="false">

                <UIOutput id="j_idt15" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false"/>

                <HtmlPanelGrid border="-2147483648" columns="2" id="j_idt16" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false">
 ....
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`<cc:insertFacet>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/cc/insertFacet.html) is not intented for the composite itself, but for composite's child which in turn expects a facet which needs to be provided externally.

E.g. a `<h:dataTable>` which supports a `<f:facet name="header">` (poor composite example, but it's just to give the idea):

```
<cc:implementation>
    <h:dataTable> 
        <cc:insertFacet name="header">
```

Which is to be used as

```
<my:composite>
    <f:facet name="header">
```

This has exactly the same effect as doing as below without a composite

```
<h:dataTable>
    <f:facet name="header">
```

The `<cc:insertFacet>` is indeed used very rarely.

The [`<cc:renderFacet>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/cc/renderFacet.html) is intented for the composite implementation itself and basically achieves the same as `<ui:define>`/`<ui:insert>` in templates and tagfiles.